# in app purchase asking for password multiple times

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have an iPhone app on the market that has three different in app purchases on it. The problem is, when a user purchases a feature, they generally get prompted for their password more than once. Is this normal? Is it something with Apple or with my code?

Here is an example of one of the purchases:

```
        InAppPurchaseManager *manager = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] init];

    [manager loadStore];

    if([manager canMakePurchases]){
        [manager purchaseFeature:@"com.myfeature1"];

        VehicleExpensesController *aViewController = [[VehicleExpensesController alloc]
                                                      initWithNibName:@"VehicleExpensesController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
        [aViewController release], aViewController = nil;

    }
```

and here is my InAppPurchaseManager.m file:

```
#import "InAppPurchaseManager.h"
@implementation InAppPurchaseManager


- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
     NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.myfeature1", @"com.myfeature2", @"com.myfeature3", nil ];
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];

// we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
NSArray *products = response.products;
proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain] : nil;

if (proUpgradeProduct)
{
    NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
    NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
    NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
    NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
}

for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
}

// finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
[productsRequest release];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
#pragma -
#pragma Public methods

//
// call this method once on startup
//
- (void)loadStore
{
    // restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    // get the product description (defined in early sections)
    [self requestProUpgradeProductData];
}

// call this before making a purchase
//
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

// 
// kick off the upgrade transaction
//
- (void)purchaseFeature:(NSString *) identifier
{
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:identifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

//
 // saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk
//
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.myfeature1"])
{
    // save the transaction receipt to disk
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"DiscountCalculator" ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
} 
if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.myfeature2"])
{
    // save the transaction receipt to disk
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"VehicleExpenses" ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.myfeature3"])
{
    // save the transaction receipt to disk
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"NoAds" ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
}

//
// enable pro features
//
- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productId
{
if ([productId isEqualToString:@"com.myfeature1"])
{
    // enable the pro features
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"DiscountCalculatorIsPurchased" ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}else if ([productId isEqualToString:@"com.myfeature2"])
{
    // enable the pro features
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"VehicleExpensesIsPurchased" ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}else if ([productId isEqualToString:@"com.myfeature3"])
{
    // enable the pro features
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"NoAdsIsPurchased" ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
}

//
// removes the transaction from the queue and posts a notification with the transaction result
//
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{
// remove the transaction from the payment queue.
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
if (wasSuccessful)
{
    // send out a notification that we’ve finished the transaction
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
else
{
    // send out a notification for the failed transaction
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
}

//
// called when the transaction was successful
//
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
[self recordTransaction:transaction];
[self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

//
// called when a transaction has been restored and and successfully completed
//
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
[self recordTransaction:transaction.originalTransaction];
[self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

//
// called when a transaction has failed
//
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
{
    // error!
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
}
else
{
    // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver methods

//
// called when the transaction status is updated
//
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
@end
```

Sorry if its a lot code - I just wanted to make sure all the relevant code got in there.

Comment: So did my answer help you? You should accept it if it did :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling 
`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];` inside `- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction`. This is what requests the password for the second time. You don't need to call `restoreCompletedTransactions` to store the details of a transaction.